# Parse a string combined of multiple enums' values

Tags: c#, parsing, enums

I have three enum types (`enum1`, `enum2`, `enum3`) whose values may contain `_` char, and a string `s` of the pattern `"enum1_enum2_enum3"`.

Now, I want to analyse the string `s` to get the three values of the enum types.

Is there an efficient way to do that?

**Edit:**
An example:

```
enum enum1 {A_1 ,B_1, C_1} 
enum enum2 {A_2, B_2, C_2} 
enum enum3 {A_3, B_3, C_3}
string s = "A_1_B_2_C_3";
```

after parsing I should get:

```
enum1 part1 = enum1.A_1;
enum2 part2 = enum2.B_2;
enum3 part3 = enum3.C_3;
```

Comment: Are you saying that the enum values are delimited by the `_` or that the actual enum values could have `_` in them

Comment: Are you tied to that format? Could you use comma separation? Because comma separation is built in for `[Flags]` enums... heck, you could probably use replace (underscore to comma)

Comment: Add enum is an enumeration of integer values.. do you mean that enum items themselve contain the underscore. i.e. Enum_1 = 0, Enum_2 = 1

Comment: By "the three values" do you mean that you want three separate enum values to be returned?

Comment: Yes I'm tied to the presented format because they are enums of 3rd library. and  I'm forced to use the pattern of  underscore separated string for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the solution can be :

```
// your enumeration declaration ...
private enum enum1 { A_1, B_1, C_1 }
private enum enum2 { A_2, B_2, C_2 }
private enum enum3 { A_3, B_3, C_3 }

// string to process 
private static string s = "A_1_B_2_C_3";

// parsing result structure
private struct ParsingResult
{
    public Type enumType;
    public object enumValue;
}
```

After making these, create a placeholder for the results :

```
ParsingResult[] results = new ParsingResult[] {
    new ParsingResult() { enumType = typeof(enum1) },
    new ParsingResult() { enumType = typeof(enum2) },
    new ParsingResult() { enumType = typeof(enum3) }
};
```

Then iterate through these results to process string :

```
for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
{
    results[i].enumValue = Enum.GetNames(results[i].enumType).Select(value =>
    {
        int cIteration = 0;
        while (cIteration < s.Length && cIteration + value.Length <= s.Length)
        {
            string toProcess = s.Substring(cIteration, value.ToString().Length);
            cIteration += value.ToString().Length + 1;
            try
            {
                object valid = Enum.Parse(results[i].enumType, toProcess);
                return valid;
            }
            catch { }
        }
        return null;
    })
    .FirstOrDefault(v => v != null);
}
```

Of course it will return `string` value and not your `enum` but this you can make using :

```
results[i].enumValue = Enum.Parse(results[i].enumType, results[i].enumValue.ToString());
```

And I think it wont make you to much trouble implementing.

Later on using :

```
foreach (ParsingResult value in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value.enumValue);
}
```

Sample output should be :

```
A_1
B_2
C_3
```

**EDIT :**

I had to modify this a bit because it wasn't working as intended. Previously if you would have :

```
static string s = "W_4_A_1_B_2_C_3";
```

Output would be inaccurate and show values like `B_2` and `C_3` meaning it will omit the first `enum`. Now after simple edit it will return only valid values.